# Flutter - How to filter list to map expansiontile

Tags: list, flutter

Is there a way to filter this list.map to only display results based on list (e.g. subjectName field != null)?

```
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: Biology, courseName: BIOL 101, courseSection: B101-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: null, courseSection: B101-2,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: null, courseSection: B101-3,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: BIOL 102, courseSection: B102-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: null, courseSection: B102-2,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: BIOL 103, courseSection: B103-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 1, subjectName: null, courseName: BIOL 104, courseSection: B104-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: Chemistry, courseName: CHEM 101, courseSection: C101-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: null, courseName: null, courseSection: C101-2,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: null, courseName: CHEM 102, courseSection: C102-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: null, courseName: null, courseSection: C102-2,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: null, courseName: CHEM 201, courseSection: C201-1,}
flutter: Courses{subjectId: 2, subjectName: null, courseName: CHEM 202, courseSection: C202-1,}
```

This results above prints an ExpansionTile for each row in list but I want to print only Biology and Chemistry where subjectName != null.

I tried to filter using ‘where’ but that only filtered the expanionTile not the list.

```
ExpansionTile(
      maintainState: true,
      title: Text("TOP LEVEL HEADER"),
      children: allCoursesList.map<ExpansionTile>((Courses eachCourse) {
        return ExpansionTile(
            //key: PageStorageKey<Courses>(item),
            title: Text("${eachCourse.subjectName}"));
      }).where((item) => item != null).toList())
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Below answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
allCoursesList.where((item) => null != item.subjectName).toSet().toList().map(//...)
```